# How to set property in cpp code in Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-source

In android if we want to set property from cpp file how it can be done.
what headers can be included and what api we can call directly to set property.

Tried executing `setprop` command from cpp file that works but wanted different approach.

Answer (score 2):

we can set property directly by including the below header in cpp file

```
#include <cutils/properties.h>
```

and setting property using below command

```
property_set("ro.myprop.server", "1");
```